# iPad App one user reporting "White Labels". Accessibility?

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface

I have a strange bug report from a user of my iPad App. She reports seeing "White Labels" and has sent me a screen shot. It seems that this must be at least partially caused by some Accessibility setting, but I cannot reproduce. She has an iPad Air2 which I do not have immediately available to me. Here are the differences:

[image]

There are 2 differences shown here. That are quite different under the covers.

- Keys: A bundled font on a dynamically created and rotated UILabel
- FX(Volume): A static UILabel in XIB with built in Avenir Next Condensed Demi Bold

Just got another eMail from her stating that the iPad is JailBroken (Arg!). But it is still odd that only some of the UILabels are impacted. If anyone has ideas on this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It was the Eclipse2 jailbreak App that caused the issue. Here is what I heard back from my user:

> OK problem is resolved. Now the key labels are black text on the iPad Air2.
>   It was the Eclipse2 settings that triggered the white text in the labels, and once Seline Redux  is "Blacklisted" under Eclipse 2 settings and then iPad must be resprung,  the problem disappears.